# Term for: People acting normally while others disbelieve

Tags: terminology, vocabulary, literary-techniques

Is there a name for the literary technique in which some people act normally about a topic or situation, while others (possibly including the reader) are incredulous?

For example, at the end of *To Kill a Mockingbird*,  Scout can hardly believe Boo Radley is in her house and sees him as a figure of her imagination, while Dr. Reynolds acts perfectly normally, saying “Evenin’ Arthur, didn’t notice you to first time I was here” and treating him as a normal person.

Comment: I'm not sure why you refer to it as a literary technique though. It's just a depiction of someone remaining calm.

Comment: I believe it's not just someone remaining calm; in the _To Kill a Mockingbird_ example, I'm pretty sure Dr Reynolds and the adults know Boo's true personality where as Scout and the youths don't - thus Scout is in disbelief and still sees Boo as a figure of her imagination while everyone else acts perfectly normally.

Comment: I am not sure if this is right, but I always thought that the situation you are referring to is an example of irony.

Comment: It could be a *surreal* feeling when everyone refuses to acknowledge the unusual character of the situation, as if in a dream.

Comment: RE: remaining calm. Oddly, Yharooer, I think your comment points out the validity of the "remaining calm" thought. Dr. Reynolds has knowledge that assists him in this, and he has the presence of mind not to be perturbed in the situation. Thus, "remaining calm" rather fits, eh? However, I think the word juxtaposition is the best answer to your question, which I believe is to describe the *variance* in the emotional reactions.

Answer (score 2):

**Juxtaposition**

NOUN

*The fact of two things being seen or placed close together with contrasting effect.*

This word describes exactly the sort of scene you gave. I am not sure if you want the word to be used in the book text or not, but if so, something like this might work: "The calm reaction of Dr. Reynolds at seeing Boo Radley juxtaposed with Scout's reaction highlights her utter disbelief of what she is seeing."

Comment: You need to link to and attribute your reference. It's interesting that some dictionaries give 'to show contrast', some 'especially for contrast', and some just the unqualified 'The fact of two things being close together, or the act of so placing them' OWTTE.

Comment: Since the OP was concerned with the contrast in reactions, I think juxtaposition is about as good a single word option as one is likely to find. I like it. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

The striking thing about the scene is the shift from the dramatic intensity of Scout's shock and astonishment to the matter-of-factness of Dr. Reynolds's greeting of Boo Radley. I'm not aware of any literary term for this particular form of dramatic contrast in tone. I do think, however, that *matter-of-fact* is a better term for Dr. Reynolds's behavior than such alternatives as *impassive*, *unruffled*, *unflappable*, or *blasé*. Here is the very brief entry for *matter-of-fact* in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003):

> **matter-of-fact** adhering to the unembellished facts; *also* : being plain, straightforward, or unemotional

Answer (score -1):

I think the best option would be "***Impassive***".

[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/impassive) defines *impassive* as:

> ***impassive***
>
> Syllabification: im·pas·sive Pronunciation: /imˈpasiv    / ADJECTIVE
>
> **Not feeling or showing emotion:**
> *impassive passersby ignore the performers*
>
> Example sentences:
>
> - *He had an impassive expression, as if he had been expecting this all along.*
> - *I was about as confused as him, but I didn't let it show, keeping an impassive expression plastered to my face.*
> - *His expression was impassive and I tried not to wilt under the searching gaze of those deep brown eyes.*

In fact, example sentence 1 seems to be closely related with your scenario!

Another alternative would be *unperturbed*, or perhaps *untroubled*, but I'd go with *impassive*.

Comment: This is an adjective to describe a person's demeanour, but the OP seems to be looking for a word to cover a scene where one or more people remain impassive whilst others are incredulous.

Comment: In the example given, the adults are not acting especially unemotional.

Comment: I don't think this addresses the question. The OP wanted to describe the variance in responses, not label Dr. Reynolds' response.